# Strip out all non alpanumeric characters and non set punctation

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, function, sql-server-2016

Hi I've taken a function to strip out alphanumeric characters and some punctuation characters from a string.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Remove_Non_Alphanumeric]
    (@String_Parameter VARCHAR(MAX)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Alphanumeric_Characters VARCHAR(289) = '%[^A-Za-z0-9| |?|,|&|\|/|.|'+CHAR(13)+'|'+CHAR(10)+'|(|)|]|[|-]%';
 
    WHILE PATINDEX(@Alphanumeric_Characters, @String_Parameter) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @String_Parameter = STUFF(@String_Parameter, PATINDEX(@Alphanumeric_Characters, @String_Parameter), 1, '');
    END

    RETURN @String_Parameter;
END
```

This mostly seems to work. However there are odd passages which have some characters returned with a ? and odder still some bullet points are changed to ? and others are left. Despite both not being in a my list of acceptable characters.

Comment: If you are getting `?` when you don't expect it, it's probably because the source is Unicode. You should probably be using `nvarchar` everywhere, not `varchar`, and prefixing string literals `N'with N'`. Print the input before you even start, I bet there are issues before your code even touches the string. Also instead of using `STUFF` to try to remove unidentified characters, why not loop through the characters in the existing string, and use those to build a new string, only adding _allowed_ characters?

Comment: You could probably do this faster with an inline tally table. What is the maximum size of your strings?

Comment: There is no max length of the string can be pretty long like 4/5 paragraphs.